# Problems with loading nlp model with deeplearning4j

Tags: java, nlp, deep-learning, deeplearning4j

so I'm trying to implement the free deeplearning library for Java called deeplearning4j to tackle a classification task in nlp.

```
public static void Learn(String labelledDataFileName) throws Exception {
    ParagraphVectors paragraphVectors = new ParagraphVectors();
    InMemoryLookupCache cache = new InMemoryLookupCache();
    LabelleDataIterator iterator = new LabelleDataIterator(new File(labelledDataFileName));
    TokenizerFactory t = new DefaultTokenizerFactory();
    t.setTokenPreProcessor(new CommonPreprocessor());
    paragraphVectors = new ParagraphVectors.Builder()
            .minWordFrequency(1)
            .iterations(3)
            .learningRate(0.025)
            .minLearningRate(0.001)
            .layerSize(400)
            .batchSize(1000)
            .epochs(1)
            .iterate(iterator)
            .trainWordVectors(true)
            .vocabCache(cache)
            .tokenizerFactory(t)
            .build();
    paragraphVectors.fit();
    WordVectorSerializer.writeFullModel(paragraphVectors, MODEL_FILE_NAME);
}
```

pretty standard, not much different from the sample provided on the net. The trained model after being fitted is then saved to a text file with the method writeFullModel. Then it can be loaded with this method

```
WordVectorSerializer.loadFullModel(MODEL_FILE_NAME);
```

The problem is, it doesn't seem to work when the model gets big. For a model file of size 120Mb, I keep getting this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal slice 7151
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.slice(BaseNDArray.java:2852)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.tensorAlongDimension(BaseNDArray.java:753)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.vectorAlongDimension(BaseNDArray.java:830)
at org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.BaseNDArray.getRow(BaseNDArray.java:3628)
at org.deeplearning4j.models.embeddings.loader.WordVectorSerializer.loadFullModel(WordVectorSerializer.java:523)
```

It loasd fine with a small model file though.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you so much.

Comment: Feel free to join the community on Gitter if you have questions: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 2):

When the IllegalArgumentException is thrown, you must check the call stack in Java’s stack trace and locate the method that produced the wrong argument.

[Here](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/nd4j/blob/master/nd4j-backends/nd4j-api-parent/nd4j-api/src/main/java/org/nd4j/linalg/api/ndarray/BaseNDArray.java) is the BaseNDArray.java class and see the lines or search for the methods you've got the error in!
see this method:

```
public INDArray slice(int slice) {
    int slices = slices();
    if(slice >= slices)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Illegal slice " + slice);
```

so,for the 120MB file, slice >= slices!
see if this can help and reply how did you solve the problem!